# Browse data from Parse.com with horizontal swipe in Swift (iOS)

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, parse-platform, uipageviewcontroller

I have an app which fetches data from Parse.com. The data contains images and strings from different profiles. I want to load this data into a swipeable view, so the user can swipe left and right to view profiles of other users.

This is NOT a like/dislike app, I just want the user to view profiles which has been loaded and sorted by a global filter set by the user. The whole view consists of 1 user, so when the user swipes left or right, it can view a new user. If the user swipes back, it shows the user the same profile as before.

I've been searching on SO and Google, but couldn't find a fulfilling answer. Some say that UIPageViewController can make this happen, others point to UIScrollView and UICollectionView.

What is your take on this?

PS. I am planning on adding a new level of navigation on top of this. So swiping left and right will make you browse users, swiping up will show you settings and swiping down your own profile.

Thanks!

-- Data that will be loaded from Parse.com backend --

- firstName
- lastName
- profilePic
- birthday
- profileBio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this tutorial to get ideas: 
https://github.com/cwRichardKim/TinderSimpleSwipeCards

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am looking for a swiping method without fancy animations. Kinda like this: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/StefanLage/SLPagingView/master/Demos/TinderLike/tinder.gif but where maybe 50-100 profiles gets loaded from Parse.com

Comment: I would put it in a UIScroll view, load up an array with your info from parse. Then make the UIScrollView big enough to store all the content. Enable paging and you will achieve a similar effect to what you posted above.

Comment: For two profiles in the array you would set the content size of the UIscroll view to the height of the window and the width is window width *2. You can centre your first image and then find the coordinates for the next one just by multiplying through by 2 again. Just need a for loop.

Comment: Wouldn't scrolling be slow and use a lot of memory if I use UIScrollView? For example for 50-100 profiles with images and other data? Thanks for your point of view and answer.

Comment: It's images that will cause memory issues. You could store them in a dictionary or array though and code it so only one image is actually being used at a time. I.e view one load image 1. Swipe to view 2, kill image 1 load image 2. You can do the same for the textfields, only display them as needed. You don't need to initialise every single image and textfield.

Comment: @Deviks Were you able to solve this? I am facing the same problems and would love to see your solution.